# Rally C#: How do i get count of features under a release worked on by defined set of owners?

Tags: c#, rally

I am currenly pulling out the below report manually from rally

>   With the ongoing of (Q2-1) release (Current)
>
> o  14 features for this release, out of which, 4 is worked on by dev team. 1 completed. 1 blocked pending further info. Rest are not assigned yet/awaiting further discovery
>
>   With the ongoing of (Q1-2) release (Previous)
>
> o   12 features in this release, out of which, 2 is still worked on by dev team, 8 completed. Rest are not assigned yet/awaiting further discovery
>
> o  Team was able to close 9 US and 4 defects with 13.5 points. 4 US  were split to next sprint 8 DE

I am trying to automate this using a console app that i can run manually or set as a task that runs every week. I want to know the following:

1. How can i get the count of features for a release value that i set?
2. How to get the count of features worked on by dev? I usually do this by checking if those features have any US worked with the owner as one of my colleagues.
3. Status of the above result? Whether it is completed or blocked or in progress?
4. The total US and defects worked on by me or my colleague in that US and how many story points it took to finish it

I have written code to do authentication and i am currently getting all the work under on release

Comment: Despite I know nothing about rally, looks like too broad. Consider reducing the question to one question and, if possible, adding a [mcve] of what you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the people who type inputs are consistent.   This code is not going to give good results if the humans input is inconsistent.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Report report =  new Report(FILENAME);
            report.Print();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Report
    {
        public static List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
        public static int numberClosed { get; set; }
        public static int defects { get; set; }
        public static decimal points { get; set; }

        public string quarter { get; set; }
        public string release { get; set; }
        public int numberFeatures { get; set; }
        public int worked { get; set; }
        public int completed { get; set; }

        string patternWith = @"With the ongoing of \((?'quarter'[^\)]+)\) release \((?'release'[^\)]+)\)";
        string patternFeature = "features";
        string patternClose = "Team was able to close";
        string patternNumbers = @"\d+(.\d+)?";

        Match match = null;
        MatchCollection matches = null;
        public Report() { }
        public Report(string filename)
        {

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);


            Report report = null;

            string inputLine = "";
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if(inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    match = Regex.Match(inputLine, patternWith);
                    if(match.Success)
                    {
                            report = new Report();
                            reports.Add(report);
                            report.quarter = match.Groups["quarter"].Value;
                            report.release = match.Groups["release"].Value;
                            continue;
                    }
                    match = Regex.Match(inputLine, patternFeature);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        matches = Regex.Matches(inputLine, patternNumbers);
                        report.numberFeatures = int.Parse(matches[0].Value);
                        report.worked = int.Parse(matches[1].Value); 
                        report.completed  = int.Parse(matches[2].Value);
                        continue;
                    }
                    match = Regex.Match(inputLine, patternClose);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        matches = Regex.Matches(inputLine, patternNumbers);
                        Report.numberClosed  = int.Parse(matches[0].Value);
                        Report.defects = int.Parse(matches[1].Value);
                        Report.points  = decimal.Parse(matches[2].Value);


                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Summary : Reports = '{0}',  Closed = '{1}', Defects = '{2}', Points = '{3}'",
                Report.reports.Count,
                Report.numberClosed,
                Report.defects,
                Report.points);

            foreach (Report report in Report.reports)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quarter : '{0}', Release : '{1}', Features : '{2}', Worked : '{3}', Completed : '{4}'",
                    report.quarter,
                    report.release,
                    report.numberFeatures,
                    report.worked,
                    report.completed);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: very detailed answer but it is not anyway related to the question I asked. The report is from rally. We have to use rally api to get the info

Comment: Use the Soap Example in Aswin link at githum.  It will return a string response.  Then use StringReader (instead of StreamReader) to process the results with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a super shitty code to get this work done. Since it was just something i tried to do on my free time to automate a manual work i was doing, i didnt spend much time following standards. But it works. The below site helped me a lot. It has example projects that can help you start off.

https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-dot-net-rest-apps

If anyone wants specific answer to the questions i raised, comment here and i will definitely help you out